# Opening an app from another app - "This app is not allowed to query for scheme"

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am unable to find a clear, precise guide on how to open another custom app from my current custom app.

I keep getting this error:

> This app is not allowed to query for scheme *myScheme*.

Comment: How is this related to the Scheme programming language?

Comment: Its related to URL Scheme in Swift 3. I have amended the tags slightly.

Comment: are you looking fro something like: Universal Links https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working by doing the following:

In the below example the master app is the main app where I want to click a button and open another app. The other app in this example is called app2.

Both of the apps must belong to the same scheme to prevent the above "not allowed" error.

In the below example the scheme is called myapps but it can be anything you set it to in the Info tab (explained below).

In app2:

1. Click on your app Target (click your app name in the the heirarchy on the left then click your app name under TARGETS).
2. Click Info tab and scroll down to URL Types.
3. Click the arrow to expand URL Types, click the + to add a new entry.
4. Enter a unique identifier in the identifier field (I just used the bundle ID for that app... e.g com.mycompany.app2.
5. In the URL Schemes field, enter a name for your URL Scheme. In this example we shall call it myapps so we enter myapps into the field. This scheme name will need to be setup in the master app. For each additional app you want to open you need to setup a different scheme name and then also add the scheme name into the master app.

In the master app:

6. Repeat steps 1 to 5 - the only change will be step 4 as the unique identifier will be different and step 5 if you are setting up multiple apps.
7. Setup a button.
8. Connect the button to an action like below:

   ```
   @IBAction func pressOpenAnotherApp(_ sender: Any) {
       openApp(appURL: "myapps://com.companyname.app2"
   }
   ```
9. Setup the openApp function:

   ```
   func openApp(appURL: String) {
        let openApp = URL(string: appURL)!

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appURL) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(appURL, options: [:], completionHandler: { (success) in
                print("Open App: \(appURL)")
                print("Status: \(success)")
            })
         }
   }
   ```

This worked for me, although the information is just through my own trial and error so it may not be 100% accurate but it works!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `canOpenURL` before attempting to actually open the URL? (You ought to in case the second app isn’t installed.) [The documentation goes into plenty of detail](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl), about the requirement of including [LSApplicationQueriesSchemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW14) in your Info.plist.

Comment: From what I understand that is only for iOS 9 and older. That documentation tells you nothing about adding URL Types. It's not a complete guide.. it tells you one tiny piece of a larger puzzle. I wanted a short guide on how to easily open 1 app from another app and I have documented how to do this below.

Comment: Reread: this is for iOS 9 *and later*.Your question indicates a problem with a particular error and this documentation explains how to avoid that error

Comment: If you want a short guide, state that in the question.

Comment: The guide you posted is for iOS 9 and older. I need iOS 10 information. I had in the title Swift 3 which people would have related to iOS 10 but a mod kept removing it so now the question looks a bit aimless. It relates to Swift 3 on iOS. It was a question how to open an app from within another app and an error message I was getting. Then I have provided a guide to solve both as I could not find any proper already existing answers or solutions.

Comment: ‘on or after iOS 9.0’ means iOS 9 and iOS 10 and iOS 11 etc.

Comment: OK. I didn't do any of that but the below solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

**You have 2 App to test this issue.**

1. **App_B** (App open from App_A)
2. **App_A** (App start direct open to App_B)

**Step : App_B**
Choose set schemes Url in App_B (name you want to redirect open for check this App_B is installed)

[image]

Ok We set  schemes Url complete.
then go to your App_A (your current App)

**Step: App_A**

1.create your project

2.create func open  schemes url

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        openApp_B_installed()

        
    }

func openApp_B_installed(){
        //LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in your Info.plist.
        let appName = "App_B"
        let appScheme = "\(appName)://"
        let appUrl = URL(string: appScheme)

        
        if let url = appUrl,
            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            print("App installed")
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: {
                    (success) in
                    if (success)
                    {
                        print("OPENED \(url): \(success)")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("FAILED to open \(url)")
                    }
                })
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }else {
            print("App not installed")
        }
        
    }
```

3. add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in info plist.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbuFI.png)

[image]

Congratulation you done.
You try to test by install App_A , App_B and install App_A only you can debug in  `openApp_B_installed()`

I hope it helps clarify and resolve the issue for this topic.
Thank you